# multiline regex match

Tags: regex

Why the regex  below not working  for the text below

Regex:

```
(?=.*\berror\b)(?=.*\balarm\b).*
```

Text :

```
ns1.alarm.abc 
ns2.error.cdb
```

In other works how to do multiline regex match?

Comment: Multiline regex is often a mode which you set in your regex engine/tool.  As for your pattern, the lookaheads look wrong to me.  Why not just match a regular pattern?

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: What regex engine / language are you using? That's crucial if you want info on how to enable multiline mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to find the strings containing either `error` or `alarm` and for that you can try the following:

Try this Regex:

`(?=.*\b(?:error|alarm)\b).*`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ip1pEV/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*\b(?:error|alarm)\b)` - Positive lookahead for checking the presence of the **words** - `error` **OR** `alarm`
- `.*` - if the above condition is satisfied, match 0+ occurrences of all characters(except a newline character)

Your regex `(?=.*\berror\b)(?=.*\balarm\b).*` does not work as it is trying to find both the words `error` and `alarm` in the same line/input string. So, you needed to put an OR condition as shown above.

**Update:**

To match both, use this.

`(?=[\s\S]*\berror\b)(?=[\s\S]*\balarm\b)[\s\S]*` as shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/ip1pEV/4)

Comment: Thanks but I need to find error and alarm in the entire text  ( not just one line )> is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: @Iamtheroot Updated the answer. Let me know if it works for ya.

Comment: Thanks Gurman. Exactly what I was looking for.